# Angular routes for blog based on title

Tags: node.js, angular, routes, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm trying to build a blog with Angular + Angular Universal because I want it to be server-side rendered (SEO reasons) and NodeJS. The posts will be fetched from API, the problem now is routing, because I want routes to be named after the title of the post.

```
    {
    "title": "Post title",
    "content": "content of an post",
    "img":"some image"
    },
    {
    "title": "Another post",
    "content": "content of an post",
    "img":"some image"
    }
```

So this should be **angularblog.com/post/post-title** and **angularblog.com/post/another-post**, this feels so wrong to specify every title in routes because there could be 10000 posts and it's impossible to manage. There has to be a better solution, but nothing comes to my mind. Could you explain how this can be achieved? or at least send me some docs that I could read about how to resolve this problem? I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: You would just use one component that would fetch the correct post. In your route file you would use something like path: ‘blog/:title’ and you would simply read the title (variable) from the router and load the correct item. Only one route is needed..

Comment: And as additional tip.. if a blog is what you are after, don’t use Universal.. go static with Scully.io. It has blog capabilities build in..